# Stryts-JQuery Plugin Issue With Double Select

Tags: jquery, struts2

I have the following code to do a doubleselect using Struts2 and the jquery plugin:

jsp:

```
<s:url id="ajaxActionUrl" value="/getStateCodesJson"/>
<sj:select name="stateCodeId"
           id="stateCodeId"
           label="State"
           href="%{ajaxActionUrl}"
           onChangeTopics="reloadSecondSelect"
           list="stateCodeList"
           listKey="id"
           listValue="label"
           emptyOption="true"
           headerKey="-1"
           headerValue="Please Select A State"/>

<sj:select name="subCodeId"
           id="subCodeId"
           label="Sub Feature"
           href="%{ajaxActionUrl}"
           formIds="mapGeneratorForm"
           reloadTopics="reloadSecondSelect"
           list="subCodeList"
           listKey="id"
           listValue="subCodeDescription"
           emptyOption="true"
           headerKey="-1"
           headerValue="Please Select A Code"/>
```

Action:

```
@Action(value = "getStateCodesJson", results = {
        @Result(name = "success", type = "json")
})
public String getStateCodesJson() throws Exception {
    stateCodeList = stateCodeService.getAll();
    Collections.sort(stateCodeList);

    if (stateCodeId != null) {
        StateCode stateCode = stateCodeService.getById(stateCodeId);
        subCodeList = subCodeService.getByStateCode(stateCode);
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

When the jsp first loads, the getStateCodesJson() method is called *3* times. However, after making the change, the action is not called again, so the second  never gets populated.

Can anyone assist?

Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the null value of the second list at the action itself, rather than transferring it to the DAO.

Else you can use a  struts2 double select tag.

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-sdoubleselect-example/) is a good example.

Comment: Not a fan at all of s:doubleselect, but it would be rather rude of me not to accept a good answer. :)